# How to generically get enumerated set of entity records by primary id with Dynamics 365 XRM Tooling SDK

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, fetchxml, dynamics-crm-365

I am attempting to write a generic method that given any Dynamics 365 entity name and a set of IDs (GUIDS) will respond with a set of entity records matching that enumerated set.  My frustration is that there doesn't seem to be an efficient way to get the API to simply use the "primary ID key" without getting it first from metadata, another (seemingly unnecessary) round trip.

Consider the following (Hacked) method:

```
    public EntityCollection HackedFetchEntityRecordsById(IOrganizationService orgSvc, string entityName, IEnumerable<Guid> primaryEntityAttributeIds)
    {
        // Defacto HACK for getting primary entity attribute
        string primaryEntityAttribute = $"{entityName}id";

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Guid guid in primaryEntityAttributeIds)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($@"<value>{guid}</value>");
        }

        string fetchXml = $@"
                    <fetch mapping='logical'>
                        <entity name='{entityName}'>
                            <no-attrs />
                            <filter>
                                <condition attribute='{primaryEntityAttribute}' operator='in'>
                                    {sb}
                                </condition>
                            </filter>
                        </entity>
                    </fetch> ";

        return orgSvc.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));
    }
```

Note that here I am simply using a defacto standard I have observed, in that it seems Microsoft has chosen to name primary id attributes on entities with the entity name followed by the string "id".  This is clearly unsafe and a terrible way to do this.

I can do it the "right" way but it is inefficient:

```
    public EntityCollection InefficientFetchEntityRecordsById(IOrganizationService orgSvc, string entityName, IEnumerable<Guid> primaryEntityAttributeIds)
    {
        // "Correct" but inefficient way of getting primary entity attribute
        string primaryEntityAttribute = ((RetrieveEntityResponse) orgSvc.Execute(new RetrieveEntityRequest
        {
            LogicalName = entityName
        })).EntityMetadata.PrimaryIdAttribute;

        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Guid guid in primaryEntityAttributeIds)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($@"<value>{guid}</value>");
        }

        string fetchXml = $@"
                    <fetch mapping='logical'>
                        <entity name='{entityName}'>
                            <no-attrs />
                            <filter>
                                <condition attribute='{primaryEntityAttribute}' operator='in'>
                                    {sb}
                                </condition>
                            </filter>
                        </entity>
                    </fetch> ";

        return orgSvc.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));
    }
```

Note that in this case, I need to make a separate service call (with all the overhead that entails) to get the entity metadata in order to discern what the primary attribute is.  Yuck.

I would like to do something like the following (fantasy/not working) method:

```
    public EntityCollection FantasyFetchEntityRecordsById(IOrganizationService orgSvc, string entityName, IEnumerable<Guid> primaryEntityAttributeIds)
    {
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        foreach (Guid guid in primaryEntityAttributeIds)
        {
            sb.AppendLine($@"<value>{guid}</value>");
        }

        // ILLEGAL XML - made up element "primaryEntityAttribute"
        string fetchXml = $@"
                    <fetch mapping='logical'>
                        <entity name='{entityName}'>
                            <no-attrs />
                            <filter>
                                <primaryEntityAttribute operator='in'>
                                    {sb}
                                </primaryEntityAttribute>
                            </filter>
                        </entity>
                    </fetch> ";

        return orgSvc.RetrieveMultiple(new FetchExpression(fetchXml));
    }
```

I would be very happy to use some other implementation of QueryBase in the RetrieveMultiple service.

Comment: "This is clearly unsafe and a terrible way to do this." - Why?

Comment: See my response to your proposed answer below!  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Since the "hacked" method should work the vast majority of the time, perhaps try the "hacked" method first by appending `id` to the entity name. If that fails, retrieve the entity metadata to get the primaryId.

Comment: Maybe - but in an abundance of caution I need to say "no".  I am working on an integration and there is nothing to stop a third-party user from (sloppily) creating custom entities (which I need to be able to deal with) that could in theory have attributes named with the pattern "entityName + id" that are not actually the primary entity attribute.  I can't risk that error condition.  Thanks though.

Comment: Good point. If you want to push it, for out of the box entities, you are assured that 'logicalName' + "id" will not be a custom field. So, for entities that do not contain "_" or start with "msdyn", the hacked method would generally be safe. That being said, when I encountered a similar issue I also reluctantly concluded that retrieving the metadata was the way to go.

Comment: So frustrating, because of course the server does (or easily could) know the primary key when it is in the context of executing the query.

Comment: I don't think it's possible to manually create fields with the "entityName + id" format (D365 creates it automatically when you create the entity), so I'd say you're safe if you append the "id". If you still don't want to take this path, I'd query the metadata and save it in a cache to avoid the extra service call every time.

Comment: Good point that the system sets the primary key field. Though, we could still create a lookup field named "entityName + id".  If there's a custom entity named `new_request` for which you create a lookup on the Account, that lookup could be called `new_requestid`. But, comparing the token before "id" to the entity's name would easily distinguish this as a lookup field on the Account... another point for the "hacked" approach. I also agree that caching the metadata could help.

Answer (score 0):

The primary key is set by CRM when the entity is created, and it follows the format of "entity name" + "id", [following this format isn't a hack](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dynamics-crm2011/developers-guide/gg307568(v%3Dcrm.5)).

If you arn't happy with that I would use the metadata service to retrieve the details once in bulk.

```
RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest request = new RetrieveAllEntitiesRequest()
{
    EntityFilters = EntityFilters.Entity,
    RetrieveAsIfPublished = true
};

RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse response = (RetrieveAllEntitiesResponse)_serviceProxy.Execute(request);

foreach (EntityMetadata currentEntity in response.EntityMetadata)
{
    currentEntity.PrimaryIdAttribute
}
```

I'm not quite sure what the concern with doing this, presumably you are making multiple service calls for each entity, one extra metadata call won't hurt. As for expecting the server to 'just know' this information; it would probably have to query the metadata tables anyway.

Finally, if someone has to supply you with entity names, you could also ask for the primary key field.

Comment: Following your link, here is the verbiage:  "Remarks
The value is usually <entity logical name> + “id”."  This use of "usually" sure sounds like Microsoft going out of their way to avoid making a contracted commitment!  Sadly I need to count on that.  I'll query and cache the metadata.  Thanks for the thought though.

Comment: It's definitely possible to change the name of the primary name attribute when creating new entities. I've come across that exact scenario before